# My website suddenly started giving Error 200 on anything AJAX related!

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

The other day my website suddenly started acting weird. When using the Flag module to flag content, i get a 200 error! The content does get flagged once i refresh the page, but when clicking the flag link i get this error below.

When editing any of my Views, and say i click on the THEME INFORMATION link to modify the theme files i get another 200 error (see image).

When trying to open modal forms, same thing. This problem seems to have come out of nowhere overnight, as my site was ok, i went to sleep, next day problems. Now, i get the error on both my own theme (when say flagging content) and also on the Admin theme (Seven) when say editing a View. So i would guess that its related to a module rather than the theme? Anyone have any idea how i can go about figuring out whats causing this? My JS is not good at all so im beat here, been on this for a few days now :(

Any help would be much much appreciated.

When flagging a content:
[image]

When editing a View:
[image]

Comment: Did you change templates for this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a change somewhere that is adding `<?php` to the beginning of all responses.

In "When editing a View" above, you can see this `<?php` at the beginning of the response text.  Everything after the `<?php` is valid JSON and so likely the valid response.

I looked at your home page at http://www.spiritmolecule.com and it also has `<?php` added to the beginning of the HTML source.  This causes the `<STYLE>` tag to be ignored. `<?php<STYLE TYPE="text/css">` gets interpreted as a single unrecognizable tag and so the CSS statement afterwards is displayed as text on the browser.

HTTP=200 normally means OK (no errors) which makes sense since it was able to respond, just it has the junk `<?php` in front.  Of course, in a file processed by PHP, `<?php` means the file is about to start some PHP code instead of HTML/JSON markup.  Did `<?php` get added to a file NOT processed by PHP (and so `<?php` is passed thru as response text)?

Only you can know what you did to get `<?php` added to the beginning of all responses, HTML or JSON.  Do you recall any other files that you changed before going to sleep?  Since the `<?php` gets added to many (or all?) responses, it is likely in a common file.

Good luck troubleshooting!

Comment: Wow thank you so much for the great answer. I purchased a theme from themeforest net website and it was a pre-setup drupal site. The only files i have changed since i got it are the files inside the theme. This extra <?php, in which sort of file would it have to be to be processed in the whole site? Would a theme file do this? Or should i be looking in a module file?

Comment: OMG your an absolute STAR i LOVE YOU. I decided to load up all the module folder and the theme folders in to Sublime and go through each file to find the extra '<?php'... I opened my theme folder and the first file was the template.php and i found that the file was empty apart from a single <?php.. i deleted this and all is fixed!!! WOW thank you